# Switch between sections in animation

Tags: css, angular, animation, css-animations

I am trying to do the section to display one by one for few seconds. For example i need to  show section 1 for 5 seconds other section should be hide and then section 2 for 5 seconds other section should be hide and then section 3 for 8 seconds other section should be hide This should be done with the infinite loop.

I am using angular 8,css3  and html.

I am really confused to how to switch between these animation in particular seconds.Because of that confusion i didn't start coding this part.

Please any suggestions.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, snippet will be help to achieve your desire result.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barlow');

body {
 background: #000; 
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
}
.container {
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
h1.main, p.demos {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
 animation-delay: 18s;
}
.sp-container {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 z-index: 0;
 background: -webkit-radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
 background: -ms-radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
 background: radial-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 35%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}
.sp-content {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 z-index: 1000;
}
.sp-container h2 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 line-height: 100px;
 height: 90px;
 margin-top: -50px;
 font-size: 90px;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 color: transparent;
 -webkit-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
 -moz-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
 -ms-animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
 animation: blurFadeInOut 3s ease-in backwards;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-1 {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
 animation-delay: 0s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-2 {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 3s;
 animation-delay: 3s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-3 {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
 animation-delay: 6s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-4 {
 font-size: 200px;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 9s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 9s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 9s;
 animation-delay: 9s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 {
 -webkit-animation: none;
 -moz-animation: none;
 -ms-animation: none;
 animation: none;
 color: transparent;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 span {
 -webkit-animation: blurFadeIn 3s ease-in 12s backwards;
 -moz-animation: blurFadeIn 1s ease-in 12s backwards;
 -ms-animation: blurFadeIn 3s ease-in 12s backwards;
 animation: blurFadeIn 3s ease-in 12s backwards;
 color: transparent;
 text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 span:nth-child(2) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 13s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 13s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 13s;
 animation-delay: 13s;
}
.sp-container h2.frame-5 span:nth-child(3) {
 -webkit-animation-delay: 14s;
 -moz-animation-delay: 14s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 14s;
 animation-delay: 14s;
}
.sp-globe {
 position: absolute;
 width: 282px;
 height: 273px;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 margin: -137px 0 0 -141px;
 background: transparent url(http://web-sonick.zz.mu/images/sl/globe.png) no-repeat top left;
 -webkit-animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
 -moz-animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
 -ms-animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
 animation: fadeInBack 3.6s linear 14s backwards;
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
 filter: alpha(opacity=30);
 opacity: 0.3;
 -webkit-transform: scale(5);
 -moz-transform: scale(5);
 -o-transform: scale(5);
 -ms-transform: scale(5);
 transform: scale(5);
}
.sp-circle-link {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 bottom: 100px;
 margin-left: -50px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: #fff;
 color: #3f1616;
 font-size: 25px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-animation: fadeInRotate 1s linear 16s backwards;
 -moz-animation: fadeInRotate 1s linear 16s backwards;
 -ms-animation: fadeInRotate 1s linear 16s backwards;
 animation: fadeInRotate 1s linear 16s backwards;
 -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
 -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
 -o-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
 -ms-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
 transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
}
.sp-circle-link:hover {
 background: #85373b;
 color: #fff;
}
/**/

@-webkit-keyframes blurFadeInOut {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
 }
 20%, 75% {
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blurFadeIn {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
 }
 50% {
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInBack {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
 }
 50% {
  opacity: 0.4;
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 0.2;
  -webkit-transform: scale(5);
 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRotate {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0) rotate(360deg);
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
 }
}
/**/

@-moz-keyframes blurFadeInOut {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
 }
 20%, 75% {
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
 }
}
@-moz-keyframes blurFadeIn {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
 }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeInBack {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
 }
 50% {
  opacity: 0.4;
  -moz-transform: scale(2);
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 0.2;
  -moz-transform: scale(5);
 }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeInRotate {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transform: scale(0) rotate(360deg);
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
 }
}
/**/

@keyframes blurFadeInOut {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
  transform: scale(1.3);
 }
 20%, 75% {
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
  transform: scale(1);
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #fff;
  transform: scale(0);
 }
}
@keyframes blurFadeIn {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #fff;
  transform: scale(1.3);
 }
 50% {
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #fff;
  transform: scale(1.1);
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #fff;
  transform: scale(1);
 }
}
@keyframes fadeInBack {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
 }
 50% {
  opacity: 0.4;
  transform: scale(2);
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 0.2;
  transform: scale(5);
 }
}
@keyframes fadeInRotate {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0) rotate(360deg);
 }
 100% {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="sp-container">
 <div class="sp-content">
  <div class="sp-globe"></div>
  <h2 class="frame-1">AWESOME</h2>
  <h2 class="frame-2">TEXT ANIMATION EFFECT</h2>
  <h2 class="frame-3">BUILD WITH CSS3</h2>
  <h2 class="frame-4">TEST IT!</h2>
  <h2 class="frame-5">
   <span>FORK,</span>
   <span>CHANGE,</span>
   <span>EXPERIANCE.</span>
  </h2>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sumit Patel.

Comment: Did this got your desire result?

Comment: Sumit Patel, I did get the result so I have already voted you.Thank you.